# Automatically saving Real time Data in stack in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am not a programmer. I need help with excel. I have table in excel which linked with web-site and display values in cells on real time basis.  I am trying to save the value of a cell which changes every after 2 Minutes. I want to save the value of the cell in another cell automatically before it changes to another value in next minute(before Automatic refreshing done in excel). since the cell is receiving real time data. I want to save the old data and use it for calculations. I want to do it automatically for me. How do I do that using excel? Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would append data to a text file, all day long, and then do some analytics on at, maybe at the end of the day, or as needed.

```
'Starting the program and sub procedure to write VBA code to write the data to a text file Append.
Sub VBA_to_append_existing_text_file()

'Declaring the strFile_Path variable as String Data Type to store the text file path.
Dim strFile_Path As String

'Assigning the Existing File path to the variable strFile_Path.
strFile_Path = "C:\your_path_here\test.txt"

'Opening the text file for Append with FileNumber as 1.
Open strFile_Path For Append As #1

'Writing to the sample text to the File using FileNumber and Write Command.
YourValue = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
Write #1, YourValue

'Closing the File using FileNumber.
Close #1

End Sub
```

Run the Macro every 2 minutes, or however frequently you want.

```
Sub my_Procedure()
    MsgBox "hello world"        
    Call test ' for starting timer again
End Sub

Sub test()
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:02:00"), "my_Procedure"
End Sub
```

You can use Excel or R for the analytics.